# GPS data on TCP IP, not on /dev/tty

Tags: ros, gps-umd, gpsd-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

UBuntu 12.04 and Fuerte

Hi ROS users.

I understand that gpsd_client ROS package needs "gpsd" process to be run on a  physical device port /dev/tty.

But my case is different, I am getting the GPS data in NMEA format over an IP 192.168.0.61 and 10002 port. I can connect to it using telnet 192.168.0.61 10002. I cannot access the server side of it, so cannot run any other process other than to accept the data from TCP IP.

I am wondering if any one of you can tell me how I can get the GPSD to take the data from TCP IP port. I want to use the ROS package which relies on GPSD process.

I found a similar question, but was not answered.

http://answers.ros.org/question/33641/how-to-get-fix-on-nmea-data-emitted-on-a-tcp-port/

Thanks and Have a Good Day!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46729/gps-data-on-tcp-ip,-not-on-/dev/tty/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the answer at http://gpsd.berlios.de/gpsd.html under section TCP feed.

Just use

gpsd -S 10001 tcp://192/168.0.61:10002

So the final data will be on local host and port 10001.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1